# How to pass an attribute to the function hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a table which is populated taking data from an array of contacts. I need to pass to the function hover one of each contact data (your image). How could he? 
Here is the code of the dynamic creation of each row. 
What would have to put behind tr, to capture it on hover?

```
   for(var i in tbContactos)
    {
        var contacto = JSON.parse(tbContactos[i]);

        $("#tblList tbody").append("<tr alt="+contacto.Imagen+">");
     .....
     .....
   $("#tblList").hover(function(event){
      var src = $(this).attr("alt");
   ............
   ............
```

Comment: what language is this??

Comment: @NishadNichoos: *Now* it's English. Previously it was Spanish.

Comment: @NishadNichoos Spanish :P

Comment: So you want to collect an attribute value from a table row when the row is hovered over? Or do you want to collect an attribute value from all rows when the table is hovered over?

Comment: Not clear of what OP needs here :/

Comment: An attribute value of a row @Mr.E

Answer (score 1):

To attach hover event you can use `.on()`, see below code -

```
$("#tblList tbody").on("mouseenter","tr",function(){
  // do stuff for mouse enter event
  var trAttr = $(this).attr('alt');
}).on("mouseleave","tr",function(){    
// do stuff for mouse leave event
  var trAttr = $(this).attr('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#tblList tbody").append("<tr onMouseOver='test(this)' alt="+contacto.Imagen+">");


function test(row){

//here you will get the entire row.

row.getElementsByTagName("td")//will return an array of columns within the row

}
```